# How to unit-test a class in a web application?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a very large web application and have created a class that calculates dates, yesterday, last week etc.

The problem I have is I have to build and run the web application each time I want to test the class. I want to be able to run the class on its own and test the outputs, rather than building the entire app each time.

I think unit testing is the correct way to do it.

Comment: yep, unit tests: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Comment: I have noticed a tiny problem in that I cannot add a unit test to my existing project. It seems to say that I need to create a separate and new project to do the unit testing...that can't be correct can it? There doesn't seem to be anyway adding a one off test

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Unit Testing.  Programming will never be the same for you.  You will wonder how you managed to live without it.

Comment: Also you can show [QuickStart](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.5) and [more interesting ideas](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/TestCase-Attribute)

Comment: Yes, you need a separate project, because you would not want to ship your tests to your customers or deploy your tests to your web server.  Nobody uses "one off" tests. The "tests" project is something you keep building on throughout the development of your project, and in your day to day work you are primarily working with your test project, not with your main application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite simple really. I right clicked on the Solution in Solution Explorer added a new unit test project from the Test options. It installed and I set up my first test and it worked.

As ever, thanks for all your guidance.